# Java source code parser

Tags: java, string-parsing

I need to programmatically extract method definition/implementation from Java source file, could you recommend any handy library that I can use?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another option is [Jflex](http://jflex.de/) and [CUP](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~appel/modern/java/CUP/). As per my usage experience, I liked the syntax more than ANTLR. However ANTLR scores more when it comes to IDE support and documentation..

Answer (score 6):

[ANTLR](http://antlr.org/) is a parser/generator that has grammars for Java (and other languages).  It can produce an abstract syntax tree (AST) that you can navigate and manipulate as you wish.

Answer (score 1):

if you look for a simple parser, i'd avise [JavaParser](http://code.google.com/p/javaparser/)
(a much heavier implementation is also included in Eclipse)

Answer (score 1):

Before going nuts with libraries, have you considered if [Doclets](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/javadoc/doclet/overview.html) could fit for your purposes? While meant for custom Javadoc parsing, Doclets actually get access to a lot of details about the classes themselves which can be used for whatever purpose.

Another similar not-exactly-intended possibility is the rather badly documented Annotation Processor functionality which, despite its name, can be used for plain code generation and general messing around and about within whatever you're loading through the class loaders.